# grouping commands in mutt macro (tag-prefix problem for complex macros)

Tags: mutt

I encountered problem with applying `tag-prefix` for macros composed with several commands.

Let start with simple example:

```
   macro index,pager E "<pipe-message>wc<enter>"
```

It works fine, I could press `E` to get line count for message under index line, or I could tag several message and using `tag-prefix` (default `;`) I have line count for all selected message. Good.

However, when I add something to my macro like:

```
macro index,pager E "<enter-command>set pipe_decode<return><pipe-message>wc<enter>"
```

then using `E` works, but `;E` still count only lines for message under index, not tagged.

It seems that `tag-prefix` is applied only for first part of macro, not for whole definition.

How can I group macro commands to get desired effect?

(PS I know that putting `macro index,pager E "<enter-command>set pipe_decode<return><tag-prefix><pipe-message>wc<enter>"` will apply for all tagged messages, but I sometimes want to run macro for current message without changings tags, so this solution, as well as setting `auto-tag` does not work for me.)